Workday Query getting stale data
Here's the Workday query that I am using to extract data:
SELECT employeeID, preferredName_FirstName, preferredName_LastName, email_PrimaryWork, cf_CFLRVManagerEmployeeID, manager_Level01, cf_CFManagerLevel02ID, manager_Level02, cf_CFEEManagersEmailForCurrentAndFutureHires, cf_CFEEWorkerIsManagerYesOrNo, businessTitle, cf_CFV_EELocationPerWorkingModel, workerType, employeeType, contingentWorkerType, costCenter, cf_division, cf_department

However, the cf_divison field and cf_department is returning back stale data.
For example, John started off in the engineering department but now has moved to the marketing department so it should just say Marketing but the data is returned as Engineering (Inactive)
How do we resolve this and get the most up to date data?
Updated permissions of the service user but that did not work

Is this in Workday WQL? what is the data source you are using in your FROM clause?
